# Problem in displaying Bitmaps on canvas

Tags: android

I am have some bitmaps which i want to display serially one after another but my  code displays only last bitmap.Can  anybody tell me why is it happening?
here is the code

class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
    private boolean _run = false;

    public Panel(Context context) {

        super(context);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        _run = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {



    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Log.i("Read","surfaceChanged is called");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Log.i("Read","surfaceCreated is called");

        while (_run ) {

            display();
        }


    }

    public void display() {

        Canvas c;

        c = null;

        try {

            c = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);

            synchronized (getHolder()) {

                onPreviewFrame();

                invalidate();

                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                c.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);

                //panel.surfaceDestroyed(panel.getHolder());
            }

        } finally {

            if (c != null) {

                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Log.i("Read","surfaceDestroyed is called");

        _run = false;


    }

  }
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? Where is the bmp coming from? Or am I just missing it?

Comment: assume the bitmap bmp is the already created when we are in this part of the code, this is the main part of the code , which is displaying the bitmap...

Comment: In order to see why only the last bitmap is being used, I need to see the code that changes what bitmap is being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your requirement is but if your are trying to create a continous horizontal image scroll. Take a look at this
https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo